# Precise definition of convex polygons/polyhedra

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, polygons, polyhedra

Is a polygon not considered convex if it has a hole?  For example, say I drew 2 (different-sized) concentric squares.  Is the inner square considered convex while the outer one is not?  Are neither considered convex?  I'm guessing the answer is the same for two (different-sized) concentric cubes.  I forgot the technical test needed to determine convexity.  If they are not convex, are they considered concave, or just "nonconvex"?

Comment: What do you call concave ? It could be a synonym for non-convex, or the complement of a convex.

Comment: A convex set is such that it wholly contains any segment drawn between two of its points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a polytope is convex when it is a [convex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set). So something with a hole is not convex, because I can pick two points on either side of the hole and the middle of the line is not inside the polytope.

> If they are not convex, are they considered concave, or just "nonconvex"?

I believe in the case of polytopes, non-convex is the same as concave (as in the [case of polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_polygon)). However, in some other contexts such as [concave functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function), concave has a more narrow meaning than just "non-convex".

Comment: For me, "convex" or "concave" refers to a polytope that can be considered as a solid object, with a definite inside and outside. There are also self-intersecting polytopes, which are obviously not solids (the term "Kepler-Poinsot solids" notwithstanding). These I would call "nonconvex" but not "concave".